# Prompted for root password even with sudoers edited with NOPASSWD

Tags: linux, ubuntu, sudoers

I'm trying to configure my sudoers file so that I'm not prompted for a password every time I need to access root privileges.

I'm still getting prompted for my password, so if anyone has advise on what I need to change it would be appreciated.

```
#
# This file MUST be edited with the 'visudo' command as root.
#
# Please consider adding local content in /etc/sudoers.d/ instead of
# directly modifying this file.
#
# See the man page for details on how to write a sudoers file.
#
Defaults        env_reset
Defaults        mail_badpass
Defaults        secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"

# Host alias specification

# User alias specification

# Cmnd alias specification

# User privilege specification
root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
jay     ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL

# Members of the admin group may gain root privileges
%admin ALL=(ALL) ALL

# Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# See sudoers(5) for more information on "#include" directives:

#includedir /etc/sudoers.d
```

——————————————————————————————————

```
jay@laptop:~$ sudo su
[sudo] password for jay: 
root@laptop:/home/jay# visudo
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to put `jay     ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL` below `%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL`, else the latter will be in your way.